# How to unpivot date range in Excel/ PowerQuery

Tags: excel, date, powerquery, date-range, unpivot

Would someone be able to tell me the best way of unpivoting the date range that currently appears in each row: start date and end date, so that the 'Title' appears row by row for each date included in the date range.

I expect the title not to appear once, but line by line as many times as the date range indicates - so if the date range runs from 01/12/2022 to 03/12/2022 the Title will appear three times with the calendar date in the column next to it: 01/12/2022, 02/12/2022, 03/12/2022.

Image of the dataset:

[image]

My current thinking is to use PowerQuery but I'm stuck. Maybe there's a clever Excel function that can do what I need. Any suggestion/ help would be awesome. Many thanks!

Comment: It' is not clear what you're expecting as a _final output_. Can you add your expected output to the post ?

Comment: Hi. I have added in a bit more detail. Please have a read and let me know if it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to read the two dates as numbers.

1. Read the start and end dates as numbers `Int64.Type`
2. Make a new column and create a list/range with `{[Date start]..[Date end]}`
3. Expand the list to multiple rows with [`Table.ExpandListColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-expandlistcolumn)
4. Switch back the three dates to `date` type

Try this :

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A C Title", type text}, {"Date start", Int64.Type}, {"Date end", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each try {[Date start]..[Date end]} otherwise null),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type date}, {"Date start", type date}, {"Date end", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I just pasted in your code to the formula bar, hit enter and it worked like a dream. However, when I clicked on Close and Load the following error message popped up: "[Expression.Error] We cannot apply operator .. to Types Null and Null     Do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You have to make sure that your dataset does not hold any row with no start/end date like this one : https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9kTk.png. Otherwise, you'll get the error you mentionned.

Comment: I added a `try.. otherwise` to handle this case and so we can keep those kind of rows in the final result, answer updated ;)